# Proving hyperbolic equality

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, hyperbolic-equations

While trying to prove a problem on catenoids intersecting orthogonally with $S^2$ I have to prove that if $a=\frac{1}{T\cosh(T)}$ where $T$ is the only real number such that $T\tanh(T)=1$ and $t$ satisfies $t^2 + a^2\cosh(t/a)^2=1 \quad (1)$ then
\begin{equation}
\tanh(t/a)=a\cosh(t/a) \quad (2)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
t\cosh(t/a)=1 \quad (3)
\end{equation}
I have manged to show that $(1)+(2)\Rightarrow(3)$ so that I'm only left with proving that $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$. Through the following algebraic manipulation
\begin{gather}
t^2 + a^2\cosh(t/a)^2=1\\
t^4 + t^2a^2\cosh(t/a)^2=t^4+a^2=t^2
\end{gather}
I got rid of the hyperbolic cosine, however other than verifying numerically that this is true I can't find any other way to prove this. I'm not sure whether there is a way to obtain an exact result but any help would be appreciated